# Query to select the amount of rows in the database for today's date?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select the amount of rows from a database if the type is a varchar?

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`order_date`) = DATE(NOW())
```

would not work as it is not stored in datetime is there any other way?

```
2011-10-30 19:14:32
```

Is what is stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`order_date`) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `order_date` is a VARCHAR, try with:

```
WHERE LEFT(order_date, 10) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `datediff` function in sql....

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, GETDATE()) <= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to change the `order_date` to `date` type and use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE order_date >= CURDATE()
  AND order_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

---

If you keep it as `VARCHAR`, you can use this variation:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE order_date >= CAST( CURDATE() AS CHAR)
  AND order_date < CAST( (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS CHAR)
```

---

Both of these, may use an index of `order_date`, if there is one.